# How to create a private VM on azure with internet access

Tags: azure, nat, azure-vm

I want to provision a VM which has no public ip so it can only be connected from other VM who have public ip. Now i can create a VM without public ip but then it does not have a internet access.

Now is there a way on Azure like on AWS where i can provision a NAT gateway or NAT instance on public subnet and let the private instances have internet connection

I also tried using NAT Gateway on Azure but it doesn't work unless i assign public ip to VM which is not what i want

I have two subnets lets say public_subnet & private_subnet , now i can ssh to my private vm from a jump but the thing is when i login to my private vm i cant install any package or even not able to ping or curl to any website. Both subnets were created using terraform so the configuration of subnets are all same there is no change is subnet configuration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Azure VMs have internet access by default, you dont have to do anything for them to have outbound access. It just works. Even without the public IP

Comment: yes it works only when VM have a public ip my question what if public ip is not assigned? it doesnt work only with private ip

Comment: if you are looking for accessing the VM from outside - you can use either bastion\jump hosts, vpn, azure bastion, or azure load balancer offers NAT support

Comment: I have two subnets lets say public_subnet & private_subnet , now i can ssh to my private vm from a jump but the thing is when i login to my private vm i cant install any package or even not able to ping or curl to any website. Both subnets were created using terraform so the configuration of subnets are all same there is no change is subnet configuration

Comment: well, I have no idea what you did misconfigure, but this should work by default. If you've blocked outgoing comms using NSG or UDRs or broken the OS inside the VM itself I cant really help you. you need to find what is misconfigured and fix it

Comment: It worked well it just missed one outbound security rule, thank you

Answer (score 0):

There's two possibilities:

First one, under the same Vnet, you provision you VM without a public ip adress and then access it using [Azure Bastion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bastion/bastion-overview). You can find more details [here](https://makram.cloud/2019/08/09/azure-bastion-the-guide).

Second one, is to provision two or more VMs in the same subnet one with public IP and the other without a public IP. and then access the one with private IP from the one with public IP.